# How to fix 'Framework resource extraction failed. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown' error in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have a Project of a UWP application. When I try to build the project on my laptop, it gives me this error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk\2.2.8\tools\CoreRuntime\Microsoft.Net.CoreRuntime.targets(195,9): error : Framework resource extraction failed. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

I tried to build the project on multiple computers and strangely on my home computer it can successfully build the project, on my other two computer it can't. It's true that on my laptop there is not too much RAM (~1.5-2Gb free before building), but on my other two computer it's the same amount, and just one computer can build it.

Comment: Hi, you can try to close other running programs to free up enough memory or try to delete the bin and obj folders in the project and regenerate the project.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately it doesn't help. I reinstalled my laptop and it still cannot build the project.

Comment: Hi, you can try creating a blank app and try to generate it. If you can, it may be that your original app requires a large amount of memory and you can try to optimize it.

Comment: Have you tried this guide to debugging out of memory error : https://blog.elmah.io/debugging-system-outofmemoryexception-using-net-tools/

Comment: Thanks for the help, i found the issue. It was the ML.NET library that was causing the issue. I removed from the project and it solved the problem.